# How to prove the Fourier coefficient of a convergent sequence converges as well

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis

So the question is,

$\,f_1, f_2,...,f:T\to C$ are integrable functions with $ \,f_n\to f$ in  $\parallel \cdot  \parallel_1  $ as $n\to \infty$. Let $k\in Z$. Prove that, the Fourier coefficient, $ \, \hat{f}_n(k)\to \hat{f}(k)$ as $n\to \infty$.

What I have got:

$\mid\;\hat{f}_n(k)-\hat{f}(k)\mid\;=\;\mid\int_{0}^{1} f(x)e^{-2\pi ikx}dx\,-\int_{0}^{1} f_n(x)e^{-2\pi ikx}dx \mid\;=\;\mid\int_{0}^{1} (f(x)-f_n(x))e^{-2\pi ikx}dx\mid$. (*)

So since$\mid f_n(x)-f(x)\mid$ can be as  small as we want, we can show somehow that(*) can be as small as well. But I don't know exactly how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just insert the absolute value into the integral. You have

$$ \left| \hat{f}_n(k) - \hat{f}(k) \right| = \left| \int_0^1 (f(x) - f_n(x)) e^{-2\pi i k x} \, dx \right| \leq \int_0^1 \left|f(x) - f_n(x)\right| | e^{-2 \pi i k x}| \, dx = \int_0^1 |f(x) - f_n(x)| \, dx = ||f - f_n||_{L^1}. $$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$\left|\int_a^b f(x)\,dx\right|\le\int_a^b \left|f(x)\right|\,dx$$

and $|e^{ix}|=1$ for real $x$.

Comment: Del Rey, please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  -Mark